# Change style lists has only one style when during signing process

Tags: docusignapi

When we pass Signature Info with Recipient, We are getting only one style on clicking change style. How can we get all possible styles? We have already enabled all possible styles from "Signature Adoption Configuration" through Preferences

```
`var r1 = new Recipient
               {
                   UserName = String.Format("{0} {1}", "cvdf", "Test"),
                   Email = Session[Keys.ApiEmail].ToString(),
                   ID = "1",
                   //SignerName = String.Format("{0} {1}", "cvdf", "R"),
                   //SignatureInfo = new RecipientSignatureInfo { SignatureName = String.Format("{0} {1}", "ertert", "R"), SignatureInitials = "R".Substring(0, 1), FontStyle = (FontStyleCode.DocuSign8)},
                   SignatureInfo = new RecipientSignatureInfo { SignatureName = String.Format("{0} {1}", "cvdf", "Test"), SignatureInitials = "Test".Substring(0, 1)},
                   Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer,
                   CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo { ClientUserId = "1" }

               };
           runningList.Add(r1);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `FontStyle` is going to limit that recipient to that font.  Unfortunately according to the [schema](https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL) `FontStyle` is required if supplying `SignatureInfo`.

```
<s:complexType name="RecipientSignatureInfo">
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SignatureName" type="s:string"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SignatureInitials" type="s:string"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FontStyle" type="tns:FontStyleCode"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```